# Table cells in the second view are not displayed

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

The table cells contained in the first view are properly represented, but the table cells contained in the second view do not appear. I can’t understand why.

**HelpController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class HelpController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

// MARK: - Initialize

@IBOutlet weak var menuTable: UITableView!
let helpMenu = ["a","b","c"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
//datasource link
    menuTable.delegate = self
    menuTable.dataSource = self

    self.menuTable?.tableFooterView = UIView()


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

// MARK: - Table View Data Source

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return helpMenu.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "HelpMenuCell")
    cell.textLabel?.text = helpMenu[indexPath.row]


    return cell
}

}
```

When i check it with `print (helpmenu.count)`, it return 3. It seems to work well until `numberOfRowsInSection`, but `cellForRowAt` does not work.

and this is my first view `InfosController.swift`

```
// MARK: - Table View Data Source
// get cell count
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "userid") != nil {
        // sign in state
        return memberMenu.count
    } else {
        // sign out state
        return nonMemberMenu.count
    }
}

// change cell text
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "InfosMenuCell")

    if UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "userid") != nil {
        // sign in state
        cell.textLabel?.text = memberMenu[indexPath.row]
    } else {
        // sign out state
        cell.textLabel?.text = nonMemberMenu[indexPath.row]
    }

    return cell

}
```

This is the code included in the first view that works properly. This works well, but I’m confused because it does not work well in the second view(`HelpController`).

ps.

[image: identifier - HelpMenuCell]

Comment: Post your code for second view (HelpController).

Comment: Make sure you assigned datasource & delegation & if numberOfSections in row returned Zero then probably cellForRow atIndex won't call.check member & nonMember menu counts

Comment: check you `identifire` properly added in cell from storyboard  HelpMenuCell`  ,,,,and also check the count of your array ,,,,,,if it is zero cell for row won't call.

Comment: Yes, I checked with print (helpMenu.count) and it was not zero.

Comment: @サンディープ  The first code I posted is HelpController

Comment: use a separate tableView controller for second view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in HelpController, In controlle  self.menuTable?.tableFooterView = UIView()
So if You are having footer view then You need to write the delegate function heightForFooterInSection and viewForFooterInSection

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? { 
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
 }

Comment: Oh my god ... I saw your writing and got a hint to solve the problem. When I removed Contstraints, I could see the tableCell.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure below things

1. Make sure you added `Delegate & DataSource` to tableView.
2. Check your `helpMenu count` is not equal to
   **Zero**.
3. If `numberOfRowsInSection` returns Zero, then probably **cellForRowAt
   indexPath won't call**.
4. Please check the method declaration once the correct syntax is

> ```
> func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath:
>  IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell { }
> ```

Comment: The problem is the HelpController. I checked with `print (helpMenu.count)` and it was not zero. We used `menuTable.delegate = self` and `menutable.dataSource = self` for delegate and DataSource connections.

Comment: check out with adding numberOfSection in tableview & also return numberOfRowsInSection directly as Int value.if it doesn't work then create a new controller & start tableView impementing

Comment: Thank you for your kindness! When I removed Contstraints, I could see the tableCell.. When I removed Contstraints, I could see the tableCell.